# Why is multiline string altered on print or write? (Python 3.6 on Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, newline, multiline

I am using Python 3.6.3 on Windows.
When I try to print a single multiline string to file like this:

```
with open('test1.txt', mode='w') as f:
    f.write('test\r\ntest\r\n')
```

Then `test1.txt` will end up containing `test\r\r\ntest\r\r\n` instead of `test\r\ntest\r\n`.

A workaround to get the desired output would look like so:

```
with open('test2.txt', mode='w') as f:
    for line in 'test\r\ntest\r\n'.splitlines():
        print(line, file=f)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You're not supposed to put the `\r`s in yourself. Text mode translates that for you.

Comment: Yeah, I know I shouldn't do that. In my case, I get the string in one go from `tablib.tsv`, however.

Comment: Why `mode='w'` instead of `mode='wb'`, if you want your data to be written literally?

Comment: I suppose that would do the job, too... Are there any corner-cases `mode='wb'` does not handle strings well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, turns out properly stating a question often leads to the answer presenting itself:

The reason for this behaviour is to be found with Python's [universal newline](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) (quoting from [PEP 3116](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/) on `TextIOWrapper`):

> On output, if `newline` is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, `os.linesep`. **If newline is `''`, no translation takes place**. If newline is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string. (Note that the rules guiding translation are different for output than for input.)

This means, when opening the file for writing, the `newline` parameter can be set to `''` to achieve the desired output:

```
with open('test3.txt', mode='w', newline='') as f:
    f.write('test\r\ntest\r\n')
```